# QED in Minkowski space VS a finite volume and their mathematical formulations

Tags: mathematical-physics, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics

I am currently trying to figure out the relationship between two different presentations of non-interacting quantum electrodynamics. The first is the usual Fock space formulation in infinite Minkowski space, the second uses a finite volume; in my example I shall use a cubic volume with side length $L$.

The way I currently understand it, the second formulation is used in order to avoid having to deal with operator-valued tempered distributions as would arise in the infinite volume case. Then one hopes that the limit $L\to \infty$ will produce the same results as in the Minkowski-space formulation?! In what way and under what circumstances is that the case?

I would also like to use this question to make sure I understand the mathematical details in both cases correctly. $c=\hbar=1$. I don't want to worry too much about the quantization procedure and just talk about the resulting quantum theory.

This paragraph explains notation. I denote 3-vectors by bold letters and four-vectors by cursive letters. If $\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\mathbb{R}^4\ni k:= (\omega_k, k_1, k_2, k_3)$, where $\omega_k=\omega_\mathbf{k}:=\|\mathbf{k}\|$ is the dispersion relation in vacuum with $c=1$. On the other hand, if $\mathbb{R}^4\ni x=(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ then $\mathbf{x}:=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The euclidian scalar product of 3-vectors is denoted $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}$ and the Minkowski Product of four vectors is denoted $x\cdot y:= x_0 y_0 - \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}$. I am following the book "Finite Quantum Electrodynamics - The causal approach" 3rd edition by G. Scharf, pp. 146-156.

In the Minkowski-space case , one quantizes the electromagnetic potential $(A^{\mu})=(\phi, \mathbf{A})$ as four independent scalar fields. I would be extremely thankful for any corrections or comments to the following. We define

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{A}^{\mu}(t,\mathbf{x})=\mathsf{A}^{\mu}(x):= \int_{\mathbf{k}\in \mathbb{R}^3} \frac{(2\pi)^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\mathbf{k}}}}\left( \mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k}) e^{-ik\cdot x})  + \mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k})^\dagger e^{ik\cdot x}  \right).
\end{equation}

This is a time dependent, operator-valued tempered distribution (?), where the Hilbert space is something like the symmetric Fock-space over the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, but I'm not sure how the set of four different creation operators is supposed to act on this space. Hence **Question 1: What is the exact Hilbert space?**

The mutually adjoint operator valued distributions $\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k}),\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k})$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
[\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k}), \mathsf{a}^{\nu}(\mathbf{k'})]=\delta_{\mu\nu}\delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'), 
\end{equation}
Consider test functions $f,g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C})$ in the Schwarz space of rapidly decaying functions.  (Scharf only considers real-valued test functions. I don't understand why.) Then the action of such a distribution is in the sense of

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(f):= \int_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3} f(\mathbf{x})\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{x}),
\end{equation}
where **Question 2: What is the action of the above operator on a general element of the Hilbert space?** (where one would have to know what the Hilbert space is)

Scharf continues to compute the commutator
\begin{equation}
[\mathsf{A}^{\mu}(x), \mathsf{A}^{\nu}(y)]=\delta^\mu_\nu\frac{1}{i}D_0(x-y),
\end{equation}

where $D_0$ is the Lorentz invariant Jordan-Pauli function for mass zero. He observes that the equation is not Lorentz-covariant and redefines the zero-component of $\mathsf{A}^{\mu}$ to be a skew-adjoint operator instead of self-adjoint, which makes the commutation relation lorentz-covariant. He observes that all expectation values of the redefined $\mathsf{A}^0$ will vanish for states in the "physical subspace" of the Fock-space in question (which is defined as the precise subspace where that is the case). **Question 3: I find this a bit suspect. Are there more elegant approaches to this problem? Or further ways of justifying the procedure?** (I like the approach where one abandons positive-definiteness of the scalar product even less though.)
He derives the free Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
\mathsf{H}=\int_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{R}^3} \omega(\mathbf{k})\sum_{\mu=0}^3 \mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k})^\dagger\mathsf{a}^{\mu}(\mathbf{k})
\end{equation}
and claims that the energy is positive definite. (This means, the spectrum of $\mathsf{H}$ is non-negative, right?) **Question 4: Does this define a unitary time evolution?** (assuming for a moment one were to use the Schroedinger picture, which one of course will not.) Scharf does not impose any gauge conditions up until this point. The discussion of Gauge and space-time symmetries does not interest me here.

===========================================================

**My main question is to relate the above to the following approach which uses a finite volume of space**: This approach is mainly following  (R.J. Glauber, Coherent and incoherent states of radiation field, Phys. Rev. 131 (1963) 2766-2788)
Say $V$ is the standard cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with volume $L^3$. (I'm not exactly sure of the mathematical details; it's probably supposed to be the open cube.)

Consider a set of functions $\mathbf{u}_k: V\mapsto \mathbb{C}^3$ (where $k$ is a set of discrete parameters) satisfying
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot {\mathbf{f}_k}=0\\
\nabla^2 \mathbf{f}_k+\frac{\omega_k^2}{c^2}\mathbf{f}_k=0\\
\int_V \overline{\mathbf{f}_k(\mathbf{r})}\cdot\mathbf{f}_l(\mathbf{r})d \mathbf{r}=\delta_{kl}\\
\text{The } \mathbf{u}_k \text{ are complete.}
\end{align}
That is, an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $L^2(V,\mathbb{C}^3)$. An example for such a system is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u}_{(\lambda, k_1, k_2, k_3)}(\mathbf{x}) = L^{-\frac{3}{2}}\mathbf{e}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}   \exp(i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}),\qquad \text{where }  (\lambda\in\pm 1, k_i\in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z})         
\end{equation}
Where the real unit vectors $\mathbf{e}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}$ are chosen orthogonal to each other (for each $\mathbf{k}$ and different "polarizations" $\lambda$) and to their respective $\mathbf{k}$. I guess these are basically the expansion functions/vectors for Fourier series in 3 dimensions. I will denote them as $\mathbf{u}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}$ and write a sum $\sum_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}$ where $\lambda$ and the components of $\mathbf{k}$ run over the discrete values specified above.

This second approach, as I have seen it, fixes the gauge before quantization. I'm not sure if that is necessary, probably not. In any case the Radiation Gauge is chosen, that is to say the Coulomb gauge $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{A}=0$ together with the condtition that the scalar potential vanishes, which can be satisfied only for the free field in the absence of charges (which is what both formulation deal with).
One then defines the 3-component operator

\begin{align}
\vec{\mathsf{\mathsf{A}}}(t, \mathbf{x})&=\sum_{\lambda=1}^2\sum_{\mathbf{k}} \frac{\mathbf{e}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}}{L^ {3/2}\sqrt{2\omega_{\mathbf{k}}}} \left(\mathsf{a}_{\lambda \mathbf{k}} e^{i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}-\omega_{\mathbf{k}} t)} + \mathsf{a}^\dagger_{\lambda \mathbf{k}} e^{-i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}-\omega_{\mathbf{k}} t)}  \right)\\
&=\sum_{\lambda\mathbf{k}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\mathbf{k}}}} \left( \mathsf{a}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}} \mathbf{u}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{x})e^{-i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}t} +  \mathsf{a}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger} \overline{\mathbf{u}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}}(\mathbf{x}) e^{i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}t}\right)
\end{align}
together with the hamiltonian operator
\begin{equation}
\mathsf{H}= \sum_{\lambda\mathbf{k}} \omega_{\mathbf{k}} (\mathsf{a}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}}^\dagger \mathsf{a}_{\lambda\mathbf{k}} +\frac{1}{2} ).
\end{equation}

Once again I'm not entirelly sure what the Hilbert space is. It is clear that one can separate the Hilbert space into sectors with fixed wave vector as one could separate the Hilbert space into sectors with fixed photon number in the first case. **I want to know what the relationship is between the two Hilbert spaces for both formulations of the theory, as well as what kind of limit procedure could be used to relate results from one to the other**. Glauber writes the state of the entire field as
\begin{equation}
| \{ \alpha_k \} \rangle= \prod_k | \alpha_k\rangle_k
\end{equation}
where a state $|\alpha\rangle$ may be seen as a certain state for the standard quantum harmonic oscillator on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. While it is intuitively clear that the description specifies an oszillator state for each wave vector and polarization, as the system is seen as a system of infinitely many non-interacting harmonic oszillators for each mode of the field, I'm not entirelly sure what the mathematical meaning of the formula is. **Would the appropriate Hilbert space for the entire field be the tensor product of the single-mode Hilbert spaces?**

Thanks a lot to anyone who read through all of the above and can give me as much a hint towards the solution of any of the questions. I'm very grateful in advance for any suggestions or references.

Comment: You seem to have at least two distinct questions. The question of how to "take the limit" from the "in a box" theory could be asked about the simpler case of a scalar field (or in general). I think you would have a better chance of getting Answers if you could ask them separately in a simple or general context.